# Как закруглить кнопку?

Tags: html

Как закруглить кнопку в форме? У меня вот такой код:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
             Логин: 
<br />
<input name="login" id="login" type="text" />
<br />
<br />
Пароль:
<br />
 <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" style="background-color: #7da7d9;" value="Войти" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно кнопке присвоить определенный класс:

```
 <input type="button" class="SuperButton" value="MySuperButton">
```

Далее в стилях:

```
.SuperButton{
             border-radius:5px;
            }
```

---

Но во-первых, этот способ не кроссбраузерный, т.е работает на всех браузерах, кроме всеми нами "любимого" IE. В IE выход - использование картинок...иначе никак.

Comment: Ну о кроссбраузерности - направда. Этот способ не будет работать еще в Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome и еще во многих браузерах. Не нужно забывать о приставках `-webkit-` и `-moz-`.

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

Answer (score 1):

1. [CSS border-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius) - для IE понадобятся дополнительные фиксы ( [одно из них](http://css3pie.com/) )
2. используем картинку для бэкграунда кнопки

Comment: Точно картинкой же можно!

Answer (score 1):

ну, например, посмотри как это реализовано здесь [twitter-bootstrap-button](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)