# Как сделать закругленную картинку?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать закругленную картинку я пробовал вот так как написано
[сдесь](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-skruglennye-ugolki-u-fotografii-fiksirovanno), но  мне не помогло. Может есть какие ни будь  другие способы?

Comment: Этот способ уже давно себя изжил, лучше используйте свойство CSS3 border-radius!

Answer (score 2):

Свойство **border-radius**. Вопрос уже был, и я на него уже отвечал **[ЗДЕСЬ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128286/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82)**.

Comment: Ой извините как удолить вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Так же как и в случае с предыдущим вопросом (про скругление кнопки ) можно использовать [CSS свойство border-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius) - для IE понадобятся дополнительные фиксы ( [одно из них](http://css3pie.com/) )